# Position div using pure css

Tags: html, css, css-position

This is a hard one to describe, but the fiddle shows what I want to do:

https://jsfiddle.net/zbh8ewqg/

I want to align the `#inner` div so that the top of the bottom div aligns with the top of the `#outer` div.

Not to tricky using JavaScript, but can it be done in pure CSS?

(Note: in practice the number of elements will be dynamic, and the height not known because, for example, the font may change, thus solutions with hard-coded numbers don't help. I'm not trying to transfer the calculation from JavaScript to my brain.)

Comment: It is unclear for me actually what output you want? Can you create screenshot for your output.

Comment: this question is unclear for me actually what you want?

but i have tried something for you https://jsfiddle.net/zbh8ewqg/2/

Comment: _...so that the bottom of the top of the bottom div aligns with the top_... This is really confusing. Can you provide more detailed information of what do you need?

Comment: Not sure I can be clearer. The result of the fiddle is exactly what I want; I just want to achieve it without the JavaScript. Clearly it can be done with a hard-coded 75px, but in practice I don't know the height of #above at design time.

Comment: @JasperKent As i know it is not possible using pure css. You need to use either javascript or jquery.

Comment: Thanks for the definitive answer, Ketan.

Answer (score 1):

try to add this code. It will give same output as mention on jsfiddle.

```
div#inner{
    position: absolute;
    top: -75px;
}
```

Comment: Problem is 75 is a magic number - it's what I'm getting for height in the js. I want something that will work however many numbered divs there are and however they are styled.

Comment: Well, I think you are looking some kind of calc() function that can be used in css. but this function not support calculation based on other class, id or property like js.

Comment: I appreciate it may not be possible. However, it would be nice. I think it fits in the declarative spirit of CSS to have a way to align the top of one div with the top of another.

Answer (score 0):

Not really sure what are you trying to achieve, because I would recommend changing the mark-up div arrangements.
But anyway, here is a pure css alternative: https://jsfiddle.net/x8f2os39/

```
enter code here
```

Comment: Again, 75 is a magic number.

What I'm trying to achieve is a menu. Actually, #outer would be the whole document. Bottom is the menu button and one, two etc the contents. Normally the contents will be hidden off the top of the page, but on activation I set #inner's top to 0 and the menu appears.

Comment: You need to modify the mark-up. the menu needs to be in an independent container. Post your HTML, and I can help you.

Answer (score 0):

If you add to your div's a fixed `line-height` then it can be very easy to calculate what value for `top`you need.

If:

```
div {
    line-height:20px;
}
```

Then you just need to add `top:-80px`to your `#inner` div (4 divs above, 20px each)

**[Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/alvaromenendez/zbh8ewqg/5/)**

Comment: First, You don't need to shout. And second, people are just trying to help, even if often people doesn't deserve it. And so, make a better question because you don't say at all the content of this div is going to be dinamic.

Comment: Sorry, but if you read the whole thread, you'll see that your solution, like many other suggestions, does not offer the flexibility I require.

Comment: As I say. Edit your question and make it better. If a question has many answers are we suppose to read every single comment on every single answer to see where you say something that should have been in your question?